# Kotlin interop with Java in VSCode; Imports cannot be resolved

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have a Java project which is built using Gradle. Recently, I decided to start using Kotlin for certain aspects, like rewriting Java Singleton classes using the Kotlin `object` keyword.
However, we use VSCode with the Java extension pack as our IDE. While **Gradle builds successfully**, we get errors in our java files saying that the import cannot be resolved and/or the the type cannot be resolved.
I've found an [issue that addresses this](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/531#issuecomment-579416374), but it's been open since 2018 and there isn't a clear fix.
Can anyone recommend a fix that works for them?

Comment: this could be caused by something as simple as missing the `@JvmStatic` annotation in the Kotlin object. Can't tell without seeing the code though. Also, if you think that your issue might be caused by VSCode, did you try another dev environment? IntelliJ would be a good start, if not to switch to it, to at least confirm that the issue is caused by the IDE and not by the code.

Comment: I do have IntelliJ and it does work there. However, IntelliJ is a heavy piece of software and is not feasible for many of us to install.

Comment: Whether to install the extension [Kotlin Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin) / 
[Kotlin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin)

Comment: I have both of those installed.